# HttpWebRequest has no close method?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I am very surprised to see `HttpWebRequest` has no close method, but its counter-part `HttpWebResponse` has. It makes me a little bit confused and inconvenient. :-)

So, we only need to call Close on response and no need to treat with request? My concern is about leaks and better resource usage efficiency. I am using VSTS2008 + C# + .Net 3.5.

Comment: (I deleted the duplicate and merged in the extra content)

Comment: you asked it **again** (now deleted)? Don't do that please...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you just need to call it on the response object.

A request does absolutely nothing on its own. It doesn't open up a socket or something. It just holds some data and you can just ignore it and throw it away if you don't need it (it's a pure managed resource and garbage collector will take care of it). Actual stuff happens after one of the `GetResponse` methods is called.

Comment: Hi, is there any MS documentation or another "official" place explaining the inner workings of HttpWebRequest/Response?

Comment: @tamberg you can get the source code and read it yourself: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Comment: Does not actually seem to work.  At least for an SSL connection, does not seem to send the close to the server.

Answer (score 4):

An analogy:

If I want to talk to you and I am already sure I want to speak to you I will simply call your name (Request).  However, is up to you to decide when, how and what to answer to me (Response).  So you will have more control over the communication than me, I just started it.

Answer (score 0):

The close method you refer to on HttpWebResponse serves to send the finished response to the Web Server. On the HttpWebRequest object, all content is available when you start processing, so there is no need to close and communicate with a server.